# What do these two functions have in common?

Tags: transformation, implicit-function

I came around these two equations

\begin{align}
y&=x^2,\ x,y\in\mathbb{R} \tag{1}\\
\exp(y')&=\exp({x'}^2),\ x',y'\in\mathbb{R} \tag{2}
\end{align}

Clearly they have something in common. I can define a function $f$ defined as

$$f\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x' \\
y'
\end{bmatrix}\right)=
\begin{bmatrix}
\log_2(x) \\
\log_2(y)
\end{bmatrix}$$

And if I apply $f$ to each pair $(x',y')$, then the equation transforms to $(1)$. So my question is if $f$ has a proper name or how these types of similar equations are called. It seems as if there is some kind of space transformation there, but it is not linear.

Comment: Is this a simultaneous system, or each of them has its own life?

Comment: Since $\exp$ is one-to-one, these two equations express exactly the same relationship between $x$ and $y$. For example, they have the same graph.

Comment: @rogerl These are not the same equations, they just have exactly the same set of solutions.

Comment: Just a comment on your notation: you cannot use quantifiers like this. What you are saying in your first formula  is "for all real numbers $x$ and $y$ holds $y=x^2$" which is clearly false for, e.g. $x= 4$ and $y=7$. Do you possibly want to say that $x$ and $y$ are reals? Then remove the $\forall$ quantifier.

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen They are from different universes, and $f$ connects them. What I mean with this is that $x$ and $x'$ has no relation, just that they are reals.

Comment: @Garmekain Are those universes parallel?

Comment: I would describe $f$ as a component-wise logarithm.